# Visual Studio Code, how to set a config to show scripts only from the root package.json

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, config, package.json

I have multiple package.json files in my project in different folders. VSCode reads scripts from all the files and shows them up in the "NPM SCRIPTS" panel. I want to show scripts only from the root package.json file. How to add config to the project to read only the root package.json or maybe set a precise path to it. Is it possible? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure why this glob works, but this setting (in `settings.json`) seems to work:

```
"npm.exclude": "**/folder-operations/**"
```

where `folder-operations` would be your root folder.